# Substitute for "prospection of" something

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

I'm doing a comparative analysis to determine the best device to be used in an academic project, and this analysis shall be recorded in a document.

For example, from all wireless keyboards available at Amazon, we should choose the best one, based on some requirements.

What is the correct term for this kind of study/analysis?

At first, I considered titling the document as "***Prospection of*** device X" (e.g., "*Prospection of Wireless Keyboards*").

However, this term does not seem to be the best one.

Comment: The word ***prospection*** barely even *exists*. Perhaps you're thinking of [***prospectus***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prospectus) *- a document describing the major features of a proposed literary work, project, business venture, etc.*, but that doesn't really suit your context either. Maybe you should just be using the term ***review***.

Answer (score 1):

Why not “A Comparative Analysis of”? I think this is probably the best term to describe the problem- and a term you used yourself in the question. “A” is usually the preferred article to use with this type of title, from my experience. I have never heard the word “prospection” and I agree that it would not be appropriate.